# What is the OST in episode 481 of one piece

Tags: one-piece, music

In episode 481 of One Piece (Marineford arc), the music start around 19:04

> When Whitebeard told his crew to leave Marineford.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *Steep Mountain*, from the *Episode of Chopper plus : Bloom in Winter, Miracle Sakura*. His track is 11.

Answer (score 0):

It's the soundtrack named "Ace".

https://soundcloud.com/alice-ni-tm/one-piece-ost-ace

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFZm9RlYzag

Comment: Thanks for your help. But, it's not this. I just found it, and it's "Steep Mountain", from the *Episode of Chopper Plus: Bloom in Winter, Miracle Sakura*, track 11.